# Best resources for mail server administration

Tags: linux, postfix

What are the best (updated) resources / manuals for sysadmins to learn how to manage a mail server (basically Postfix on linux)?

I'm talking about advanced topics such as mail server replication, troubleshooting (eg. identify and blocking problematic accounts), logs interpretation, configuration tuning and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give the obvious: http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html

Basically: study until your eyes bleed, and search for specific problems as encountered. No one guide will be the end-all especially as things change.

Comment: you're right, there's no better documentation :)